# How to type 'v-model'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify `v-date-picker` in a project and the code is working but I have a TypeScript error on the use of `v-model`:

```html
<v-date-picker title="Start Date" width = "200" v-model="workingDate" @click:save="newDate"/>
```

The error is:

```
Type '{ toString: () => string; toDateString: () => string; toTimeString: () => string; toLocaleString: { (): string; (locales?: string | string[] | undefined, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; (locales?: LocalesArgument, options?: DateTimeFormatOptions | undefined): string; }; ... 39 more ...; [Symbol...' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.ts(2322)
index.d.mts(2757, 13): The expected type comes from property 'modelValue' which is declared here on type '{ header?: string | undefined; style?: StyleValue | undefined; title?: string | undefined; inputMode?: "calendar" | "keyboard" | undefined; multiple?: boolean | undefined; ... 57 more ...; "onClick:save"?: (() => any) | undefined; } & Record<...>'
```

I have uploaded a working demo, which also shows the TS error, on the [Vuetify playgound](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

There's a possible solution [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) but that needs access to the component code which I don't have for `v-date-picker`.

Comment: Is this component already completed Ported to vuetify 3 ?

Comment: No, it's currently in 'labs', although it was fully available in  Vuetify2. I have looked on github issues for the new version and there's no mention of TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in v3.3. Apparently, VDatePicker's [`modelValue`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-model-value) is typed to be an array, but this is only true when the [`multiple`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-multiple) prop is set. Similarly, the [`update:modelValue`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#events-update:modelValue) event is said to pass an array, but it is actually a simple date (without `multiple`).

Using Date objects is correct. I don't think there is anything you can do about the error (except file a bug report).

Comment: I did suspect that!  I have filed a report.